# How to replace some text in a text area when a link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, replace

I'm trying to find and replace a users website address with their shortened url in a text area when a link is clicked. I haven't got very far but at the moment I can get it to replace all the text in the text area

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="short_url_link"><%= @user.short_url %></a>

$(function(){
  $(".short_url_link").click(function(){
  $( "#mention" ).val($(this).text());
 });
});
```

So when the user clicks on the short url link the website address (`@user.website`) in the text area is found and replaced with the short url (`@user.short_url`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about doing the things like that:

```
$(function(){
    $(".short_url_link").click(function(){
        var mention = $("#mention");
        var prevousText = mention.text();
        var shortURL = $(this).text();
            var regex = new RegExp(("<%= @user.website %>").replace(/\//g, "\\/").replace(/\./g, '\\.'), "i");
        mention.val(previousText.replace(regex, shortURL));
    });
});
```

Comment: That looks great. I get the following error though (I've added spaces to the error so that it isn't turned into a link) ReferenceError: - www is not defined
mention.val(previousText.replace(/http:// www .madeupurl.com/g, shortURL));

Comment: I need to escape the slashes in the url regex

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
  $(".short_url_link").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
  $( "#mention" ).val($(this).text());
 });
});
```

reference **[event.preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)**